# Loading db properties into spring context file in stand alone maven project?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have one **stand alone maven project**. i am using spring now. i wanted to use hibernate also. can i place all database related properties in an external properties file and load them into spring context file? Also mine is stand alone project. can i use @Repository, @Service, @Autowired annotations?

i am loading spring context as below:

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(//passing spring context file path)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> can i place all database related properties in an external properties
>   file and load them into spring context file?

Yes, [use `<context:property-placeholder />`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer)

> Also mine is stand alone project. can i use @Repository, @Service,
>   @Autowired annotations?

Yes, [use `<context:annotation-config />`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) along with [`<context:component-scan />`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-autodetection)

In most cases, Spring doesn't care (or pretends not to care) whether it's run from a Main Class, a Servlet container or a JavaEE server.